# Why was the massive outflow of silver before the first Opium War so bad for the British Empire?

Tags: currency, economic-history

### TLDR

I am a person without any significant knowledge of economics, so even though I have (I suspect) some partial answers, I need a better understanding of these.

### Background and question

In accounts of the [First Opium War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Opium_War), it is usually emphasised that the large trade deficit between the British Empire and the Qing Empire (“China”) was something the former greatly desired to reverse. My question is:

**Why was said deficit so undesired?**

Below I summarise a few points, which I, however, only partially understand.

#### Weakening the Currency

[Shapiro](https://www.cirsd.org/en/horizons/horizons-winter-2019-issue-no-13/the-third-opium-war), for instance, writes:

> Capital inflows to China in terms of silver increased by a factor of
> five between 1760 and 1780 alone. For the British Empire, which relied
> on the strength of the pound sterling for its economic power, the
> situation was especially disadvantageous and ultimately untenable.

This implies that the trade deficit would weaken the currency. This is not obvious to me, since currency strength denotes the purchasing power vis-a-vis other currencies. Neither is it obvious to me, why the Empire should desire a strong currency. Perhaps it has to do with needing the Indian rupee to be weak in comparison with the pound, so as to import from there?

#### Deflation

This is a point that I have thought of myself. I assume that, since Pounds would become rarer, there might be deflation —- which, I gather, at some point is undesirable due to slowing economic growth.

This argument could be wrong, if other metals played a significant role in the economy. However, I gather that [confidence in paper money and the gold standard came a bit later, precisely as a consequence of the silver drain discussed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard).

#### Halting the Trade with China

This seems straightforward. Since the Chinese would only accept payment in silver, the lucrative trade would be halted, once the Empire’s silver was gone.

#### Belief in Mercantilism

It seems that [mercantilist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercantilism) economics put great stock by a positive trade balance. Perhaps this was still a factor, despite Adam Smith already having published his work.